# What is this syntax error ? (Testing Hapi.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I'm just trying to test Hapi.js and, whatever I code, I got this error :

```
node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:145
        Items.serial(this.connections, (connectionItem, next) => {
                                                            ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gilles/exo1/node_modules/hapi/lib/index.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
```

Where does come form this syntax ...() => {... to make a function ?
What I did bad to use Hapi ?

Thank you very much

Comment: The syntax is similar to that of an [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is an ES6 feature. Are you running node with `--harmony` argument ? Otherwise these features are not supported as of yet.

Comment: That piece of code you posted has two `(`s and only one `)`. That's basically what this message is trying to say. That's probably because your parser thinks the statement should be over. It doesn't accept `=>` in that position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is called [Arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You use hapi 10 or later which requires node 4+, but you have an older version of node which doesn't support arrow functions yet. The solution is to upgrade your node version to 4 or 5.